# Taxa de crescimento utilizando PHP

Tags: php

Estou com problemas para realizar um simples calculo de crescimento mensal utilizando PHP. Ocorre o problema de que não é possivel fazer divisões por zero.

A formula usada é a seguinte:

```
$taxaDeCrescimento = ((($quantidadeMesATUAL - $quantidadeMesPassado) / $quantidadeMesPassado) * 100);
```

Eu estou me baseando esse calculo com essa fórmula de [crescimento](https://pt.wikihow.com/Calcular-uma-Taxa-Percentual-de-Crescimento-Anual). 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria que esse calculo funcionasse em meses passados onde obteve o valor de quantidade igual a zero. Ou seja, se mes passado obteve quantidade 0 e esse mês teve quantidade 2. Obtenha uma porcentagem de crescimento de 200%. Qual seria a solução para esse problema?

Comment: O que você está calculando é o crescimento relativo e não há como calcular isso em relação ao zero. Ter uma taxa de crescimento de 200% significa que você duplicou o valor anterior. Se era 100, ficou 200; se era 500, ficou 1000. A taxa de crescimento de 0 para 2 (ou qualquer valor) tende ao infinito.

Comment: É exercício de faculdade ???

Comment: Não @VirgilioNovic, é um problema que estou resolvendo em um sistema

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss essa forma na pratica do sistema que estou fazendo funcionaria perfeitamente. Pois a tal da "quantidadeMesAtual" nunca chega a zero. Porém na hora de realizar os meus testes se são funcionais, percebo que em todos os meses com essa tal "quantidade" existe diversos que chegam a zero. Pois não havia inserido nada no perido para que essa  quantidade não seja zero.

Comment: Eu estou principalmente em duvida do que posso fazer a esse respeito.

Comment: Mas se a situação de quantidade zero não deve acontecer em produção, então não vejo porque considerá-la na conta. Basta você fazer um `if` verificando se é zero e retornando um erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, você poderia tentar testar para quando for zero, dividir por 1, assim a divisão não daria erro e retornaria o valor original:

```
$taxaDeCrescimento = ((($quantidadeMesATUAL - $quantidadeMesPassado) / (($quantidadeMesPassado) ? $quantidadeMesPassado : 1)) * 100);
```

Mas isso só funcionaria se mudasse o parâmetro da divisão, mantendo o da subtração intacto.

Usando seu exemplo: ((2 - 0) / 1) *100 -> 2-0=2 -> 2/1=2 -> 2*100= 200%

Espero ter sido claro e conseguido te ajudar.

Comment: Você conseguiria simplificar utilizando o operador *elvis*: `$quantidadeMesPassado ?: 1`, mas de qualquer forma fazer a divisão por 1 irá retornar um valor errado (matematicamente falando). Se eu sair de 0 para 2 ou sair de 1 para 2 eu teria a mesma taxa de crescimento. Não faz sentido.

Comment: Isso depende, pois se o valor atual for 5 e o anterior 0, 5-0=5 e a divisão seria por 1, sendo qualquer número dividido por 1 igual a ele mesmo, o valor da equação seria 5, sendo a multiplicação após isso.